# Atomic aggregate check before update

Tags: postgresql, transactions, atomic, isolation-level

I have a table with many records, an enumerated column, and a highly multithreaded environnement.

```
CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM
    ('UNCONFIRMED', 'REGISTERED', 'VALIDATED', 'PAID');
```

Our system allows 6000 `validated` statuses, precisely. This value is dynamic and will increase later but will never go down.

We have to check the number of validated records before allowing the update:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE status='VALIDATED';
```

- If the result is below `< 6000` (for a start), we change the status to
  `validated`.
- If the result is `>= 6000`, we do not change the status, and
  throw an Exception.
- We must never go above that number

I though about:

- isolation levels
- table lock
- select for update
- update where + a subquery (see below)
- another?

```sql
UPDATE table
   SET status='VALIDATED'
   WHERE (
        SELECT count(*)<6000 FROM table WHERE status='VALIDATED'
   ) AND id=:id;
```

***Which would be the best way to do this and guarantee atomicity between hundred of threads?***

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to have hundreds of threads trying to do something that can't be done.  What else will they be doing?  Once you have reached the limit, how and how often does the limit get unreached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"update where + a subquery" will not be sufficient, you would need to couple it with a table lock, an advisory lock, or an increased isolation level.  Otherwise it will allow multiple updates in flight at the same time to complete and exceed the count.

"select for update" seems like a horrible idea. It would have to lock every row in the table for every attempt, which would generate a huge amount of churn.  And it still might miss some depending whether rows are ever inserted with status='VALIDATED'

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't know about Advisory locks, and that could solve my issue here. Would you mind explaining which isolation level would be required for it to work? Do you suggest advisory locks or increased isolation?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion :

(a) Create a dedicated `status_counter` table with a constraint on the `counter` column which checks that its value remains under the limit (6000) :

```
CREATE TABLE status_counter (status status primary key, counter integer CHECK (counter < 6000)) ;
```

(b) Set up the counter :

```
INSERT INTO status_counter
SELECT 'VALIDATED', count(*) FROM my_table WHERE status='VALIDATED' ;
```

(c) Update the `status_counter` table by trigger on `table` when a new row is inserted or updated :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_insert ()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.status = 'VALIDATED'
  THEN
      UPDATE status_counter
         SET counter = counter + 1
       WHERE status='VALIDATED' ;
  END IF ;
  RETURN NEW ;
END ;
$$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION table_insert() ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_update ()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.status IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'VALIDATED' 
  AND OLD.status IS DISTINCT FROM 'VALIDATED'
  THEN
      UPDATE status_counter
         SET counter = counter + 1
       WHERE status='VALIDATED' ;
  ELSEIF NEW.status IS DISTINCT FROM 'VALIDATED' 
  AND OLD.status IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'VALIDATED'
  THEN
      UPDATE status_counter
         SET counter = counter - 1
       WHERE status='VALIDATED' ;
  END IF ;
  RETURN NEW ;
END ;
$$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table_update BEFORE UPDATE OF status ON table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION table_update() ;
```

(d) Starting from now, each time a user inserts or updates a row in `table`, the `counter` is updated by trigger, and the update fails when the `counter` reaches the limit raising an exception and preventing the row to be inserted or updated.

The atomicity between hundred of threads should be guaranteed because they all attempt to update the same unique row in table `status_counter`.

demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2c264ba3b7ed86e25abda614d8345829).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I wanted to avoid the counter solution because then I would have to drop and re-create the constraint from application code every time the dynamic limit (of 6000) changes. Is there a way to guarantee this limit without constraints and triggers?

Comment: Changing the limit is not a big deal : `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS status_counter DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS counter_limit ;` and then `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS status_counter ADD CONSTRAINT counter_limit CHECK (counter < 20) ;`.